# Difference between Galois extension and separable extension

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

a Galois extension is defined as an extension which is separable and normal.
I am looking for an example of an extension which is separable but not Galois. Apparently it is the case of$$\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$$ but I don't really understand why. Can someone explain ? It is separable because $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is separable over $\mathbb Q$, but why is it not normal over $\mathbb Q$ ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Notice that the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is contained in $\mathbb R$, but the other two roots of the irreducible polynomial $x^3-2$ are complex. Thus, the field extension contains only one of the three roots of an irreducible polynomial, thus is not normal.

Comment: Thanks fot the quick answer. However I still don't really understand the link between the two characterizations of a normal extension ; namely

$L$ is a normal extension of $K$ if one of the following equivalent conditions holds :

(i) every $K$-homomorphism from $L$ to an algebraic closure $\Omega$ of $K$ is an automorphism of $L$

(ii) every irreducible polynomial of $K[X]$ which has at least one root in L, has all its roots in L.

Comment: This would mean that if $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not normal, there should be a $\mathbb Q$-homomorphism of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ to $\mathbb C$ which is not an automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$. I just don't see what such a homomorphism would be like...

Comment: A detail... $\mathbb{C}$ is not the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. It's smaller.

Answer (score 2):

$\eta : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $\eta (\sqrt[3]{2})=\sqrt[3]{2}. \omega $ is a $\mathbb{Q}$ homomorphism.

But then....